# asynchronous events being fired

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing an application that has multiple threads running simultaneously.
Each thread talks to a web-sever and downloads different amounts of data.
I would like to display the total progress for all the threads in the application.

Each thread raises an event every 1 megabyte downloaded:

```
 RaiseEvent My_Event(Size_Downloaded as double,Total_Size as double)
```

Is there a way to display the total downloaded in the main form without getting cross thread errors?

it doesn't have to be instantaneous, so a timer might work?

Comment: Without code the question is a little broad. What kind of "cross threading errors" do you mean? Cross thread UI calls? You can avoid them by using [Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/a1hetckb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) in the event handler. (I'm not used to vb syntax so I don't answer with a full code example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change event signature and add id of the Thread
and use timer to display show total

```
Dim _info As New ConcurrentDictionary(Of Integer, DLoadInfo)

Sub MyEvent(id As Long, Size_Downloaded As Double, Total_Size As Double)

    Dim v = New DLoadInfo() With 
        {
            .SizeDownloaded = Size_Downloaded, 
            .TotalSize = Total_Size
        }

    _info.AddOrUpdate(id, v,
            Function(key, oldValue)
                Return v
            End Function
         )
End Sub

Private Sub TimerDisplay_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim sizeDownloaded, totalSize As double
    For Each o As DLoadInfo In _info.Values
        sizeDownloaded += o.SizeDownloaded
        totalSize += o.TotalSize
    Next
    TextBoxSizeDownloaded.Text = sizeDownloaded 
    TextBoxTotalSize.Text = totalSize 
End Sub

Class DLoadInfo
    Public property SizeDownloaded As Double
    Public property TotalSize As Double
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

As Rene said, depends on what cross threading error you get. If you're getting any cross-thread UI call errors, then the best way to handle it, imo, is through delegates.

Just wrote this one up really quickly as an example:

This will cause a cross-thread UI error.

```
Private Sub DoThis()
    Dim bgw As New BackgroundWorker
    AddHandler bgw.DoWork, AddressOf bgwDoWork
    AddHandler bgw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bgwDone

    bgw.RunWorkerAsync(1)

End Sub
Private Sub bgwDoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim i As Integer = e.Argument
    RTB.AppendText(CInt(i + 2).ToString)
End Sub
```

However, with a delegate sub, we can access the control on the main thread:

```
Private Sub DoThis()
    Dim bgw As New BackgroundWorker
    AddHandler bgw.DoWork, AddressOf bgwDoWork
    AddHandler bgw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bgwDone

    bgw.RunWorkerAsync(1)

End Sub

Private Delegate Sub UpdateText(item As String)
Private Sub Update_RTB(item As String)
    If RTB.InvokeRequired Then
        RTB.Invoke(New UpdateText(AddressOf Update_RTB), item)
    Else
        RTB.AppendText(item)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub bgwDoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim i As Integer = e.Argument
    Update_RTB(CInt(i + 2).ToString)
End Sub
```

Don't hesitate to let me know if you need me to clarify this any further.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather simple solution I use for multithreaded events:

```
Private Sub ThreadSafeRaise_MyEvent(Size_Downloaded As Double, Total_Size As Double)
    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() ThreadSafeRaise_MyEvent(Size_Downloaded, Total_Size))
    Else
        RaiseEvent My_Event(Size_Downloaded, Total_Size)
    End If
End Sub
```

If the form (which is `Me` in this code) needs to be invoked, the method uses lambda to invoke it and then the method is executed once again. But this time when the form is already invoked, the event can be raised normally.

To raise the event you just need to call (without the `< >`):

```
ThreadSafeRaise_MyEvent(<size downloaded here>, <total size here>)
```

And that's it! No further invocation needed, raising your event this way is thread-safe. You also don't need to declare any delegates of your own, as the lambda (the `Sub()` expression) does that for you.

Hope this helps!